# How to remove button from the system toolbar?

Tags: lsfusion

Can you tell me if this bottom system toolbar can be removed?

I need to remove this system button for a particular field.  How can I do this?

[image: example of lsfusion system refresh button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is fine-tuning and would be difficult to apply to a specific field. In particular, remove the refresh button.  It is not very clear the relevancy and frequency of such a setting.  But if you really need to implement it, I would use css. It would be easier to apply to a form. Maybe there are other options, but that's up to the developers. I don't know

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction